# PDO is inserting "null" for empty values

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I am using PDO for writing to sqlite database.

```
// $dbo is an instance of PDO

$query     = "INSERT INTO items (id, name, rank) VALUES (:id, :name, :rank)";
$statement = $dbo->prepare($query);

$values = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Name', 'rank' => '');
 
$statement->execute($values);

$values = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Name', 'rank' => NULL);
 
$statement->execute($values);
```

After executing any of these, I expect "rank" to be an empty string or even a NULL is acceptable.
But what I get in the database is `'null'`, yes a string `'null'` value, not the real `NULL`.

Could not find any solution after several attempts.

Comment: What is the datatype of the `rank` column?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware varchar, null allowed

Comment: OK, thanks. I think SQLite does probably return a real `null`, but PHP/PDO turns any result, like that, into a string, because it doesn't know `NULL` as a result. Then again I would expect an empty string as a result of your first insert, after all, an empty string is also a string.

Comment: I [tested this with SQLite](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=b97fae44b85e161de2437abf23d2b8c8) and indeed, inserting an empty string does return an empty string, not `null`. The problem is probably somewhere else in your code.

Comment: Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I did that, and I confirm everything is fine before statement execute. Probably something is wrong with PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending NULL directly in this line

```
  $values = array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Some Name', 'rank' => NULL);
```

Comment: That doesn't work too. Updated the question